# C: Format %s expects argument of type char* in funny strings program

Tags: c, string, scanf

I am making a program to check for funny strings. To understand the exercise [read this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/funny-string).

My code is here:

```
#define MAX_STR_LENGTH 10

char* reverse(char *str) {
    char *reversedStr = malloc(strlen(str));
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_STR_LENGTH; i++) {
        for (int j = MAX_STR_LENGTH - 1; j > 0; j--) {
            reversedStr[i] = str[j];
        }
    }
    return reversedStr;
}

int isFunny(char *str, char *reversedStr) {
    for (int i = 1; i < MAX_STR_LENGTH; i++) {
        if (str[i] - str[i - 1] != reversedStr[i] - reversedStr[i - 1]) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int main() {

    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */    
    int numberOfStrings;
    scanf("%i", &numberOfStrings);

    char **strings;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStrings; i++) {
        scanf("%s", &strings[i]);
    }

    char **reversedStrings;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStrings; i++) {
        reversedStrings[i] = reverse(strings[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStrings; i++) {
        if (isFunny(strings[i], reversedStrings[i])) {
            printf("Funny\n");
        }
        printf("Not funny\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The error I am getting is the following:

```
solution.c: In function 'main':
solution.c:35:9: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char **' [-Wformat=]
         scanf("%s", &strings[i]);
```

I don't understand why though.

My aim was to make an array of strings, called strings, and store there all the strings that I read. Why is strings[i] a char** ?

I would appreciate any help or tips.

Thanks!

Comment: `strings[i]` is not a `char **`, but `&strings[i]` is.

Comment: In `char *reversedStr = malloc(strlen(str));` you do not malloc enough space and you forgot about the null terminator

Comment: in `isFunny` what happens if the strings are actually shorter than MAX_STR_LENGTH ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you have a `char *` and you are passing it's address, which is wrong, `scanf()` wants a `char` pointer for each `"%s"` specifier, and the fix for your code is to use

```
char string[10];
scanf("%s", string);
```

the array automatically becomes a `char` pointer when passed to `scanf()` like above, but that's not enough.

Your array of `char` now as I suggest it is of fixed size, and even if it wasn't, using `scanf()` like that is dangerous, suppose that each array in the array of `char` arrays has `10` elements, then each string you want to read must have only `9` characters, you can instruct `scanf()` to stop reading when it already read `9` characters like this

```
scanf("%9s", strings[i]);
```

If you don't do this, then reading extra characters will be possible, but illegal, causing what's called *undefined behavior*.

If you want an array of strings, say of `5` strings with `9` characters each, then you can try

```
char strings[5][10];
int  i;
for (i = 0 ; i < 5 ; ++i)
    scanf("%9s", strings[i]);
```

<sub>**Note**: You need the `&` address of operator for example, when you pass an `int` value, because `scanf()` modifes the data pointed to by the passed pointer, so you need to make a pointer to the `int` variable where you want to scan the value, for that you use the `&` address of operator, since you pass a pointer containing the address of the variable.</sub>

<sub>**Suggestion**: Always check the return value of `malloc()`, it returns `NULL` on failure, and dereferencing a `NULL` poitner, is undefined behavior, you must be careful not to cause undefined behavior because it's too hard to debug.</sub>

Comment: Worse -- the OP's `strings` is a just an uninitialized pointer -- he never allocates any memory to hold the strings, or the pointers, so they're all just dangling.

Comment: @ChrisDodd you are right, the type wouldn't be `char **` if they were arrays.

Comment: Why would I want to use char string[10]? I want to declare an array of strings, not a string.

Comment: Then use `char strings[NumberOfStrings][NumberOfCharacters]`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. What is the difference between declaring the array of string like you said, with declaring it like char **strings = ... ?

Comment: The difference is that `char **` is not an array of arrays but an array of pointers, which is quite different, for example memory layout is very different, you need to allocate memory dynamically for it, which if you are learning I wouldn't recommend yet.

Comment: Ok. I replaced char** strings with strings[...][...] and now I have a new error: assignment to expression with array type at line 40. What do you think is the cause of the problem?

Comment: You can't assign to arrays, if you are trying to store a string into an array read about `strcpy()`.

Comment: @pk163 `reversedStrings` should be declared as: `char *reversedStrings[numberOfStrings];`